# How to get nearest elements score in sorted set

Tags: node.js, redis

I have sorted set with a score like

```
 zadd myset 10 "user 1"
 zadd myset 12 "user 2"
 zadd myset 14 "user 3"
 zadd myset 15 "user 4"
```

I want to fetch 1 nearest element from the sorted set

> for instance for "user 2" nearest is "user 1" or "user 3"

```
ZRANGEBYSCORE myset  12 -inf +inf LIMIT 0 1
```

and also want to delete the same element from the sorted set

Please guide me. TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find the nearest elements you'd first have to call [`ZRANK`](https://redis.io/commands/zrank) to obtain the member's rank:

```
redis> ZRANK myset user2
(integer) 1
```

Follow it with a [`ZRANGE`](https://redis.io/commands/zrange) to fetch the closet members from the rank-1 to the rank+1:

```
redis> ZRANGE myset 0 2 WITHSCORES
1) "user1"
2) "10"
3) "user2"
4) "12"
5) "user3"
6) "14"
```

Now you can compare the differences between the scores of the original member and its neighbors. Assuming you chose user1, you can remove it from the set with [`ZREM`](https://redis.io/commands/zrem):

```
redis> ZREM myset user1
(integer) 1
```

This logic can be coded in your application, but you can further streamline and ensure the atomicity of the flow by composing it as server-side Lua script (see the [`EVAL` command](https://redis.io/commands/eval)) like this one:

```
local rank = redis.call('ZRANK', KEYS[1], ARGV[1])
if not rank then
  -- Key or member not found
  return nil
end

local r1, r2 = rank-1, rank+1
if r1 < 0 then
  r1 = 0
end

local member, score
local range = redis.call('ZRANGE', KEYS[1], r1, r2, 'WITHSCORES')
if #range == 2 then
  -- One member - must be a zset of cardinality 1
  return nil
elseif #range == 4 then
  -- Two members
  if range[1] == ARGV[1] then
    member, score = range[3], range[4]
  else
    member, score = range[1], range[2]
  end
else
  -- Three members. Ah ah ah.
  if range[4] - range[2] <= range[6] - range[4] then
    member, score = range[1], range[2]
  else
    member, score = range[5], range[6]
  end
end

redis.call('ZREM', KEYS[1], member)
return {member, score}
```

This is how it looks when you run it:

```
$ redis-cli --eval script.lua myset , user111
(nil)
$ redis-cli --eval script.lua myset , user2
1) "user1"
2) "10"
```